# How to prevent google action from closing the conversation?

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm developing a Google Action through DialogFlow and a webhook (that will run on a Nest Hub) that I want to act like this:

- the user invokes the action "Hey Google, talk to ACTIONAME"
- through the Default Welcome Intent ("hooked" to my web service) the Action replies to the user and open a website

```
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
  conv.ask('Hi! I'm opening your site')
  conv.ask(new HtmlResponse({
    url: 'https://MY_IOT_SITE'
  }))
})
```

- now, the user could be "silent" for mins or hours, but I'd like to prevent Google Actions to close the ACTIONNAME and return to the clock, while until now the action closes after a couple of minutes

Is it somehow possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. The platform intentionally places an upper bound on how long an action can run without any user input. This is done so that an action cannot occupy the device longer than expected and prevent future inputs from unintentionally getting routed to your action rather than the Google Assistant.

You can take a look at [additional guidelines](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas/web-apps#guidelines_and_restrictions) when developing your web app.

Since your question refers to an IoT-related website, you may want to take a look at the [Smart Home](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/overview) reference, which provides an alternative way to let users control smart home devices with their voice or built-in graphical widgets.